# How do i stop all my levels running at the same time in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, class

Hi everyone i am in the process of making my first game and i am new to the whole process.
I have created a game where my levels are all split into different classes.

Recently i discovered that when i run the game all the levels on different classes are also running in the background. Which i guess is why the loading screen i have does not work.

i was wondering if there is a way to stop certain classes from executing until i actually click on the level.

Any help would be appreciated , thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you instantiate your classes just when you need them ?
After that think about a dispose method on your level class so when you don't need it you can dispose it and remove it from the display list.

ex:

```
var level1:Level1 = new Level1();
stage.addChild( level1 );
//...
// when you don't need level1 anymore:
level1.dispose(); // in that method, remove all listeners, stop timers, null objects...
stage.removeChild( level1 );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . In my document class i have the function to run level one which contains the "var level1:Level1 = new Level1(); and then the addChild part" but when i place a trace on the external level1 class it runs though level1 but does not read the function in the document class. I was wondering why would my levelone class run when it has not been told to on the document class. thanks

Comment: @user2902746 You should provide your initialization code in your question, and probably some information about pre-placed objects ar design time.

Comment: No worrys guys i found what was causing the problem.
I was using the 3 frame preloading method and on the second frame i had all my assets including the levels. Which must have caused it to start running.

I just need to figure out how to preload it without frame 2 making all the classes run. 

Thankyou for the help.
I will keep the section of code from @Binou because it will be useful for disposing of my levels. Thanks again ( p.s i will accept your answer as i cannot use my own until a few more hours )

Comment: @Bagel: Try this: Move the assets into frame 2 of a MovieClip, which itself is on frame 2 of the main timeline. This (for me) tricks Flash into not loading the assets as it passes through the frame.